# Date span - only show end date if different than start date

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, razor

I am showing a schedule for different events.

Some events are multiple days, so I would like to show the following possible displays depending on circumstance:

Jan 25

Jan 25-28

Jan 25-Feb 2

The code that I have that does not work properly is this:

```
@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.STARTTIME, "{0:MMM d}")

@if (@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ENDTIME, "{0:MMM d}") != @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.STARTTIME, "{0:MMM d}"))
    {
    @: &nbsp;-&nbsp;

    if (@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ENDTIME, "{0:MMM}") != @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.STARTTIME, "{0:MMM}"))
      {
        @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ENDTIME, "{0:MMM d}")
      }
      else
      {
        @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ENDTIME, "{0: d}")

      }

}
```

It seems that I am missing something simple, cut I cannot figure it out. It does not error, it just always displays the Jan 25-Feb 2 option regardless of the end date.

Comment: That's a lot of (apparently unnecessary) `@Html.ValueFor()` calls. Why not just use the DateTime value directly?

Comment: @jpieps, rather than showing code and output, please explain the scenario that you wish the code to do in the sequence. When do you want to see only the start/end date? Also try to use ```Model.ENDTIME``` or ```Model.STARTTIME```. Furthermore, use the date time objects to compare rather than parsing the string and comparing the strings. This can give unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks -- to be more clear, the STARTTIME is a DATETIME field in the database/model, and the ENDTIME is a field. The display is for a list of events. Some of the events are single day, that is easy. Some of the events are multiple day, that is pretty easy as well. But some of the multiple day events start in one month and end in a different month. I want the display to show as I listed, I do not want it to show Jan 7 - Jan 8 or Jan 7 - Jan 7, OR Jan 7 - 1 (in the case of the 1 being in February).

Comment: I need to compare not the WHOLE DATETIME, just first the days to see if it starts/ends on the same day and then the MONTH to see if it spans a month.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it....

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     DateTime END = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ENDTIME.Value);
     DateTime START = Convert.ToDateTime(item.STARTTIME.Value);
 @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.STARTTIME, "{0:MMM d}") //Show start time

 @if (Convert.ToInt32(END.Month) > Convert.ToInt32(START.Month))
 {
      @: &nbsp;-&nbsp;
      @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ENDTIME, "{0:MMM d}")
 }
 else if (Convert.ToInt32(END.Day) > Convert.ToInt32(START.Day))
 {
      @: &nbsp;-&nbsp;
      @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ENDTIME, "{0: d}")
  }
}
```